# Selenium find_element_by_id not functioning as expected

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
browser = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

browser.get("https://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/")

time.sleep(3)


cookie = browser.find_element_by_id("bigCookie")
cookie_count = browser.find_element_by_id("cookies")

actions = ActionChains(browser)
actions.click(cookie)

productNames = []
for i in range(18):
    productNames.append(browser.find_element_by_id("productName" + str(i)))

print("product names: ", productNames)

productPrices = []
for i in range(18):
    productPrices.append(browser.find_element_by_id("productPrice" + str(i)))

print("product names: ", productNames)

def purchase(count,cps):
    pass

def start_clicking():
    for i in range(500):
        actions.perform()
        count = int(cookie_count.text.split(" ")[0])
        cps = cookie_count.text.split("per second : ")[-1]

start_clicking()
browser.quit()
```

I'm trying to create a bot to automatically play cookie clicker. For now I'm just trying to get the bot to click the cookie and then create a list of the product names and prices. When I run I get numerous lines of incomprehensible text. For example when i is equal to 4 I want it to append Factory to the list since when I go into inspect I find this line in the elements tab:

```
<div class="title" id="productName4">Factory</div>
```

nd I also want to add the price into another list e.g.
`<span class="price" id="productPrice4">130,000</span>`
so 130000 in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing

```
for i in range(18):
    productNames.append(browser.find_element_by_id("productName" + str(i)))
```

and

```
productPrices = []
for i in range(18):
    productPrices.append(browser.find_element_by_id("productPrice" + str(i)))
```

You are getting web elements, not their texts.
If you wish to collect those texts you should do

```
for i in range(18):
    productNames.append(browser.find_element_by_id("productName" + str(i)).text)
```

and

```
productPrices = []
for i in range(18):
    productPrices.append(browser.find_element_by_id("productPrice" + str(i)).text)
```

Comment: Thanks it now works if I get the price directly like `cursorPrice = browser.find_element_by_id("productPrice0").text` that will give 15 which is correct but for some reason the list still ends up empty.

Comment: product names:  ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
productPrice0
productPrice1
productPrice2
productPrice3
productPrice4
productPrice5
productPrice6
productPrice7
productPrice8
productPrice9
productPrice10
productPrice11
productPrice12
productPrice13
productPrice14
productPrice15
productPrice16
productPrice17
Cursor 15
product names:  ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
Grandma 100

Comment: I added print("productPrice" + str(i)) to the loop just to make sure that was working correctly that's why the output might seem strange.

Comment: Is there a good way to share my code as a response because there's not enough characters in a comment  should I just click answer my question or ask a new question. Sorry for responding so late. I really appreciate the help!

Comment: If my answer helped / resolved the problem please accept it. If there are still problems the better is to ask a new question for that. You can also update this question but it will not be on the top of questions so other people will not see this.